# Считывание данных с устройства Bluetooth low energy rfcomm python3

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth

Столкнулся с проблемой. Имеется устройство bluetooth с низким енергопотреблением т.е. BLE. Цель отправить на устройство команду и получить в ответ данные. Устройство работает по RFCOMM. Собственно код который имеется, но он не даёт результата - пишет что устройство в выключено
from bluetooth import *
import socket

```
class Work:

    def __init__(self):
        self.rfcon = BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
        # self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = '**:**:**:**:**:**'
        self.port = 1
        self.data = '0x01 0x00 0x00'

    def scan_device(self):
        connection = self.rfcon.connect((self.server, self.port))

        print('con ===>>> ', connection)
        senddata = self.rfcon.send(self.data)
        print('senddata ====>>>> ', senddata)
        data = self.rfcon.recv(256)
        if not data:
            print("no data!!!")
            self.rfcon.close()
        else:
            print(data)

            self.rfcon.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Work()
    a.scan_device()
    a.rfcon.close()
```

Сделал через другую библиотеку - код:

```
from bluepy.btle import *

class Work:

    def __init__(self):
        self.initialize = Peripheral()

    def scan_devices(self):
        scanner = Scanner()
        devices = scanner.scan(10.0)

        for dev in devices:
            print("Device %s (%s), RSSI=%d dB" % (dev.addr, dev.addrType, dev.rssi))
            for (adtype, desc, value) in dev.getScanData():
                print("  %s = %s" % (desc, value))

    def connect_to_device(self):
        print('start con')
        connection = self.initialize.connect('**:**:**:**:**:**', 'public')
        print('initialize complite')
        return connection

    def check_device_status(self):
        print('test ====>>> ', self.initialize.getCharacteristics())
        cmd = '0x01 0x00 0x00 0x20 0x00'.encode('UTF-8')
        print(cmd)
        status_device = self.initialize.readCharacteristic(cmd)

        print('Device status => ', status_device)

    def diconnect(self):
        self.initialize.disconnect()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Work()
    a.connect_to_device()
    a.check_device_status()
    a.diconnect()
```

Он даёт подключение но не отправляет команду и не возвращает значение так как эта библиотека не знает что такое RFCOMM.
Возможно кто сталкивался с данной проблемой в питоне и знает как её решить?

Comment: BLE и RFCOMM несколько разные вещи. RFCOMM есть только у Bluetooth Classic. У BLE может быть реализовано через SPPoverBLE (реализация зависит от производителя). Но там принцип работы совершенно другой.

Comment: Да вы совершенно правы. Если работать с устройством BLE (т.е. низким уровнем), тогда очень удобными библиотеками можно считать PYGATT, Bluetooth.ble, и Pygattlib. В них документация очень хорошо описана и приведено большое количество примеров как работа (запись-чтение с одной ячейки), так и запись в одну ячейку, а чтение с другой по средствам подписания на прослушивание. Примеры работы с BLE [pygatt](https://github.com/peplin/pygatt/blob/master/samples/basic_bluez_gatttool_sample.py) и [pygatt 2](http://www.cypress.com/forum/proc-ble/pygatt-and-cypress-ble-dongle)

Comment: Это называется не ячейка а characteristic (характеристика) и у нее есть значение (value). У некоторых characteristic можно value читать. У некоторых - писать. Я Вам посоветую глянуть для начала ну хотя бы на вот это: www.btframework.com/ble.htm (игнорируйте все, что относится конкретно к коду, просто посмотрите про структуру BLE GATT сервисов). Следующим шагом - посмотреть какие сервисы реализованы на вашем устройстве. Ну и дальше уже думать, как с ним работать. Можно также глянуть, вдруг у устройства таки есть поддержка Classic SPP (с любого Android телефона можно глянуть).